# При выборе вырианта в селекте, подставляем к варианту цену, как реализовать?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Выбираю в селекте вариант, в селекте есть data-priceid="3",  1,2,3,4,5, это цены, каждое число относиться к цене, ниже подписал, эта цена выводиться в id result. Выбрали вариант, считался data-priceid="3" и подставилась цена которая выводиться в result.

```
<div id="catAprice">1000</div>  1
<div id="catBprice">1200</div>  2
<div id="catDprice">1100</div>  3
<div id="catEprice">1300</div>  4
<div id="catCprice">1400</div>  5
```

Можно было конечно data-priceid="3" не делать, а где value, вывести числа.
Но я с value значение, название поля передаю в бд. А если там будут числа, то в бд попадает число.

```js
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
   var $selected = $(this).find(":selected");
  $('#results').html($selected.data("priceid"))
})
```

```css
.results{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="catts" id="mySelect" class="js-select2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="0">Выберите</option>
  <option value="А (L - Мототранспортные средства)" data-priceid="1">А (L - Мототранспортные средства)</option>
  <option value="B (M1 - Легковые авто)" data-priceid="2">B (M1 - Легковые авто)</option>
  <option value="B (N1 - Грузовые авто до 3.5 тонн)" data-priceid="3">B (N1 - Грузовые авто до 3.5 тонн)</option>
  <option value="C (N2 - Грузовые авто 3.5 - 12 тонн)" data-priceid="3">C (N2 - Грузовые авто 3.5 - 12 тонн)</option>
  <option value="C (N3 - Грузовые авто свыше 12 тонн)" data-priceid="2">C (N3 - Грузовые авто свыше 12 тонн)</option>
  <option value="D (M2 - Автобусы до 5 тонн)" data-priceid="4">D (M2 - Автобусы до 5 тонн)</option>
  <option value="D (M3 - Автобусы свыше 5 тонн)" data-priceid="1">D (M3 - Автобусы свыше 5 тонн)</option>
  <option value="E (O1 - Прицепы до 0.75 тонн)" data-priceid="3">E (O1 - Прицепы до 0.75 тонн)</option>
  <option value="E (O2 - Прицепы 0.75 - 3.5 тонн)" data-priceid="3">E (O2 - Прицепы 0.75 - 3.5 тонн)</option>
  <option value="E (O3 - Прицепы 3.5 - 12 тонн)" data-priceid="2">E (O3 - Прицепы 3.5 - 12 тонн)</option>
  <option value="E (O4 - Прицепы свыше 12 тонн)" data-priceid="3">E (O4 - Прицепы свыше 12 тонн)</option>
</select>

<div id="catAprice">1000</div>
<div id="catBprice">1200</div>
<div id="catDprice">1100</div>
<div id="catEprice">1300</div>
<div id="catCprice">1400</div>

<br />

<div id="results" class="results">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Формулировка огонь.. Вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: походу я запутал ))), при выборе селекта, считываем id, и подставляем цену и выводим ее. Я поправил чуть описание, чтоб понятнее было.

Comment: "считываем id" это data-priceid ? "подставляем цену" это которая находится в дивах <div id="catAprice">1000</div> ?

Comment: да, верно..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
  var $selected = $(this).find(":selected");
  $('#results').html($("#prices div").eq(+$selected.data("priceid") - 1).text());
})
```

```css
.results {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="catts" id="mySelect" class="js-select2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="0">Выберите</option>
  <option value="А (L - Мототранспортные средства)" data-priceid="1">А (L - Мототранспортные средства)</option>
  <option value="B (M1 - Легковые авто)" data-priceid="2">B (M1 - Легковые авто)</option>
  <option value="B (N1 - Грузовые авто до 3.5 тонн)" data-priceid="3">B (N1 - Грузовые авто до 3.5 тонн)</option>
  <option value="C (N2 - Грузовые авто 3.5 - 12 тонн)" data-priceid="3">C (N2 - Грузовые авто 3.5 - 12 тонн)</option>
  <option value="C (N3 - Грузовые авто свыше 12 тонн)" data-priceid="2">C (N3 - Грузовые авто свыше 12 тонн)</option>
  <option value="D (M2 - Автобусы до 5 тонн)" data-priceid="4">D (M2 - Автобусы до 5 тонн)</option>
  <option value="D (M3 - Автобусы свыше 5 тонн)" data-priceid="1">D (M3 - Автобусы свыше 5 тонн)</option>
  <option value="E (O1 - Прицепы до 0.75 тонн)" data-priceid="3">E (O1 - Прицепы до 0.75 тонн)</option>
  <option value="E (O2 - Прицепы 0.75 - 3.5 тонн)" data-priceid="3">E (O2 - Прицепы 0.75 - 3.5 тонн)</option>
  <option value="E (O3 - Прицепы 3.5 - 12 тонн)" data-priceid="2">E (O3 - Прицепы 3.5 - 12 тонн)</option>
  <option value="E (O4 - Прицепы свыше 12 тонн)" data-priceid="3">E (O4 - Прицепы свыше 12 тонн)</option>
</select>

<div id="prices">
  <div id="catAprice">1000</div>
  <div id="catBprice">1200</div>
  <div id="catDprice">1100</div>
  <div id="catEprice">1300</div>
  <div id="catCprice">1400</div>
</div>
<br />

<div id="results" class="results">

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а путаницы не будет? а как js рассчитывает, куда подставлять какой вариант. Типа по тому как расположены цены.

Comment: @ws17 Я ничего не понял. Путаницы не будет.

Comment: Вопрос, а как прятать результат ! я просто вставил туда (руб), теперь торчит. Показывать при выборе пункта в селект, а так прятать, я запихивал так еще <div id="catAprice">(<?php echo $user->getcatAprice() ?> <strong>руб</strong>)</div>, но так глюк, я цену потом в бд передаю и он мне с руб передает. или как с результата брать только числа? можно же так.

Comment: И вопрос по теме, в теме мой первый скрипт, который берет тупо значение, если допустим для одного селекта стоит цена, я допустим выбрал и цена показывается, а если я другой пункт выбираю где нет цены, то он мне так и показывает результат который вывел, а надо не показывать. $('#resultPriceTaxi').html($selected.data("price"));

Comment: @ws17 Что такое "(руб)", и куда Вы его "вставили"?

Comment: <div id="resultPrice"> руб</div>, вот так, и если я не выбрал пункт в селекте чтобы цена вывелась, то у меня торчит тупо (руб), что не есть красиво.

Comment: @ws17 Перестаньте употреблять слово "тупо". Вы на за школой курите с местной шпаной, а общаетесь (пытаетесь общаться) с программистами.

Comment: Добавил в скрипт $('#resultPrice').show(100);, и в див style="display:none", теперь, (руб) без цены не показывает.